# Logged out css WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, dropdown

In this WordPress website, these section [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6kJT.jpg)choices, where the mouse is, link to a PDF. How can I get these to disappear, be unclickable, or redirect to the login screen if a user is logged out? Right now, logged out users can click it and it links to its PDF.

Comment: Perhaps you may want to consider reading this post for future reference http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html it helps point out some good tips to get your answers faster. In the mean time you may want to provide some code for the css and html and or other php code in question.

Comment: Stack Overflow is specifically for programming questions, so your question is considered out of scope. However, there is a very similar community specifically for WordPress. Suggest you post your question in https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Standard WordPress does not have this feature. You need to find a plugin which adds this feature to WordPress, that is, the ability to show or hide menu items based on whether the user is logged in. Here is one such plugin: https://www.wpexplorer.com/custom-menus-wordpress-users/